# Security of URL called via AJAX

Tags: ajax, security

How do you properly lock down the file called via AJAX? How do you stop someone from calling the response URL directly and getting a response?

To help explain, I'll use an example of an auto-suggestion feature; Specifically, typing in a few letters will bring up a list of all members that match that phrase.

So somewhere in the Javascript you define url of "http://mysite.com?code=". Then in the look up script we have

```
loginRequest.open("GET", url + characters, true);
```

and it returns XML of all members that have "characters" somewhere in their name. What is to stop a hacker from entering that URL directly into a browser and repeatedly sending new name snippets in an effort to get my entire member base?

No web example I've come across seems to address this concern.

Am I just being (incorrectly) paranoid?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the URL can be accessed directly or not. It can be accessed, that is all that matters.

Comment: If you don't have any type of authentication and a simple GET can request a page on your site, then anyone can request those pages at any time.

Comment: A key thing to remember is AJAX doesn't really make the web work differently. You still need to do all the things you normally would to protect a file. AJAX is just a mechanism to make requests and delivery more convenient to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL address is available on the client side, you can't totally prevent a hacker or any bot from making repeated queries to it and not to give any response. 
You should at least use some kind of server side authentication to ensure that only the valid user is able to access the data.

And of course, this valid user may also be malicious, therefore you should carefully design the system to ensure that you don't send away any critical data.

Comment: I have updated the scripts a bit and added security. When the page is called it creates a variable called 'security_string' which is a base64 encoded string containing user id, session id, and a MD5 chksum which is based off the ids and some salt. I then updated the url to be "var url= ajax_url + '?security=' + security_string + '&data=' + characters;". The AJAX file decodes, validates, and then does it's thing.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add some usage limitations if you're worried. Count how many requests there are per IP and lock it down to a certain amount each day.

Also consider if anyone will see any value in your user list. Do you publish any valuable information about your users which someone may be interested in crawling? Is this a real problem?

Answer (score 0):

If Security is important couldn't you use session id and validate it inside your ajax handler?

Answer (score 0):

with a "rasonable" threshold checker/throttle
and on violations have any action like captha or false informtion or wathever
with loged or not loged users, as google and others do with their stuff